Can you work on Chol Ha'moed if you'll be fired otherwise?
According to Halacha, may Jews work on Chol Ha'moed if they will get fired otherwise? So, if not working will mean they get fired and will necessarily lose income, do rabbis give a Heter under those conditions?

Sounds like that would be davar ha'aved

@shmosel na, sounds like menias revach. All your possessions are just fine.

Not if loss if income means loss of your house bc you can't pay your mortgage. Also income itself

@Dude I don't know what you are talking about. Loss of income is literally what the words מניעת רווח mean

One of the reasons permitting melacha on Chol Hamoed is davar ha-aved, the loss or damage of either money or possessions. Melacha may be done on chol hamoed to prevent a loss of this type if the necessary measures cannot wait until after the festival.
Davar ha-aved refers to the loss of something in one's possession, not to the loss of new profit. As such, losing one's job by not working on Chol Hamoed is a davar ha-aved since something already in one's possession will be lost, i.e., his source of income. In this instance, one is permitted to do a melacha.
However, if by failing to work one faces only the loss of wages for the days of Chol Hamoed, this is simply a loss of new profit and melacha is forbidden.
Source: R Dovid Zucker and R Moshe Francis' Chol Hamoed, a comprehensive review

I don't understand the difference you are making between new wages for these days and new wages for future days. Both are new profit. Similarly a source of income for these days and a source of income for future days are both equally [arguably] something owned.
